# How to find the difference between two formatted dates in days?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following content:

```
df =
  start      end
  01/April   02/May
  12/April   12/April
```

I need to add a column with the difference (in days) between `end` and `start` values (`end - start`).

How can I do it?

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df.startdate = pd.datetime(df.start, format='%B/%d')
df.enddate = pd.datetime(df.end, format='%B/%d')
```

But not sure if this is a right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"start":["01/April", "12/April"], "end": ["02/May", "12/April"]})
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"])
df["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end"])
df["diff"] = (df["end"] - df["start"])
```

**Output:**

```
         end      start    diff
0 2018-05-02 2018-04-01 31 days
1 2018-04-12 2018-04-12  0 days
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start']+'/2018', format='%d/%B/%Y')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end']+'/2018', format='%d/%B/%Y')

df['diff'] = df['end'] - df['start']

#        start        end    diff
# 0 2018-04-01 2018-05-02 31 days
# 1 2018-04-12 2018-04-12  0 days
```